# How to use File Entity module?

Tags: 7, files

I read documentation first: https://drupal.org/node/1591498 and installed Media 2.x.
I don't see any other docs in module files.

Then I added two additional fields to Application file type.

Now I want to create node with file field. Sample xls file is uploaded via node form but I see only standard description field for this file after upload.

Where I can find and edit those two fields that I added in file type?